# Drag item in scrollable widget

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to drag items in a widget.

The problem is that I want the widget to be scrollable (wider than the screen). How can I achieve this?

I can position the elements outside of the screen (e.g. x is big), but when I do the drag I get the offset in global coordinates which I cannot use for position.

Thanks!

Attached is a small example.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Drag Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('drag demo'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        child: Container(
          width: 5000,
          color: Colors.red.withAlpha(50),
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Item(text: '1', x: 100, y: 300),
              Item(text: '2', x : 300, y: 300),
              Item(text: '3', x : 500, y: 300),
              Item(text: '4', x : 700, y: 300),
              Item(text: '5', x : 900, y: 300),
              Item(text: '6', x : 1100, y: 300),
              Item(text: '7', x : 1300, y: 300),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class Item extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text;
  final double x;
  final double y;

  Item({Key? key, required this.text, required this.x, required this.y}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => ItemState();
}

class ItemState extends State<Item> {
  late double cx;
  late double cy;

  @override
  void initState() {
    cx = this.widget.x;
    cy = this.widget.y;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned(
      left: cx,
      top: cy - 80,
      child: Draggable(
        feedback: Center(child: Text(widget.text)),
        child: Container(
          child: Text(
            widget.text,
            textScaleFactor: 2,
          ),
        ),
        childWhenDragging: Container(),
        onDragEnd: (details) {
          setState(() {
            cx = details.offset.dx;
            cy = details.offset.dy;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Self answering. Found one possible solution to this, maybe there is better one.
The solution I found is to add controller to the SingleChildScrollView, listen to the changes and propagate the controller to the buttons.

So the the _MyHomePageState I add the following:

```
class _MyHomePageState ... {
 ScrollController _controller = ScrollController();
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller.addListener(() {
        debugPrint('offset = ${_controller.offset}');
    });
  }
  ...
}
```

And I pass the _controller as parameter to each Item widget.

Then in the ItemState, my onDragEnd looks like:

```
onDragEnd: (details) {
  setState(() {
    cx = details.offset.dx + widget.controller.offset;
    cy = details.offset.dy;
  });
}
```

(main.dart is here https://gist.github.com/ekeydar/d97812849cd89868ebbb903c566ba952)